# Connect SharePoint web parts to a database

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

How do I connect a SharePoint web part to a SQL Server database?

Comment: The question is a little bit too generic. Could you please elaborate a little bit on what you are trying to do?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003633/wss-3-0-list-populated-from-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest way would be to simply have a SQL query in your web part to a database of your choosing.  Done.  Remember, web parts are Web Controls running in an asp.net http context.  You can have anything there.

There are other middle men available like the Data Viewer Web Part, BDC, [SQL Reporting Services for SP 2007](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2007/02/19/microsoft-sql-server-2005-sp2-reporting-services-integration-with-wss-3-0-and-moss-2007.aspx) and much more.  Good luck.