# WSS 3.0 list populated from SQL query

Tags: sharepoint

I am looking for a way to maintain a SharePoint list of employees and their employee ID. I have the data in SQL and would like to get it into a list to use as a look up. I do not have access to a BDC.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Write an SPTimerjob that runs daily / weekly, updating / adding data from SQL to the list. Here's a link to a primer on custom timerjobs.

[Andrew Connell's blog](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/articles/CreatingCustomSharePointTimerJobs.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to duplicate your data inside SharePoint or just want a way to view it? You can just create a custom web part or use a 3rd party tool such as [Data Viewer Web Part](http://www.lightningtools.com/pages/lt%20data%20viewer%20web%20part.aspx)

Regards,

Phill

Comment: Create a custom web part that will call SQL Server and do the query.